# Why is this email message getting truncated?

Tags: oracle, email, smtp, clob

I use the following procedure to send emails:

```
procedure write_clob(p_connection in out nocopy connection, p_clob in out nocopy clob)
is
      v_len   integer;
      v_index integer;
begin
        v_len := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
        v_index := 1;

        while v_index <= v_len loop
            utl_smtp.write_data(p_connection, dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, 32000, v_index));
            v_index := v_index + 32000;
        end loop;
end write_clob;
```

Long emails seem to get truncated. I tested with a message of v_len == 28811, which is smaller than 32000. Yet, I noticed that it does not get truncated if I change the buffer size to 3200:

```
procedure write_clob(p_connection in out nocopy connection, p_clob in out nocopy clob)
is
      v_len   integer;
      v_index integer;
begin
        v_len := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
        v_index := 1;

        while v_index <= v_len loop
            utl_smtp.write_data(p_connection, dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, 3200, v_index));
            v_index := v_index + 3200;
        end loop;
end write_clob;
```

I tried with some other sizes, e.g. 30000 and 28000, but it still gets truncated. Notice that 28000 is smaller than the message length - 28811. Moreover, `utl_smtp_write_data` accepts varchar2, which should allow up to 32767:

```
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA (
   c     IN OUT NOCOPY connection, 
   data  IN VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET ANY_CS);
```

I could just use 3200 as my buffer size, but I'd prefer not to apply a bandaid fix without understanding what's going on.

Could anyone please help me understand why this strange behavior is occurring? Thanks!

I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3.0.

Comment: What length is it getting truncated to? Not sure it would matter, but what character sets are you using - do you have multibyte characters? Have you aded debugging to the loop to check basic things like how long the substr is, how many times it goes round, et. - to clarify that it's definitely the `utl_smtp` call that is losing data?

Answer (score 1):

We're running into the same issue, and the magic number seems to be 2,000.  If you're seeing that 3,200 works, then I'd guess you're passing single-byte character data, with the real limit being 4,000.

After beating our heads against this issue, I had a "duh?" moment (complete with uncertain question mark).  I keep reading that the limit on the data being written should be 32k, but the variable type in the call to `write_data()` is a varchar2.  Although a varchar2 in pl/sql should allow up to 32k, I suspect that the *database* varchar2 limit of 4,000 bytes is being imposed within the `utl_smtp.write_data()` function - whether by virtue of some internal limitation, or through an explicit truncation of the incoming buffer, I don't know.

I would recommend keeping your chunk size to 2,000 or less to avoid any double-byte character set headaches down the road.  In fact, every example on the web seems to use 1,900... an odd number whose existence might be traced back to 13-year-old code on the asktom.oracle.com site:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1739411218448#2624320100346519249

To quote:

> I wish I remembered why it was in 1900 byte chunks, but that was 9 years ago. I guess I should have 
>   been more specific with the comment.
>
> Tyler

I find this more amusing than I could possibly express.